# Set iOS Appstore notification default style

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

When submitting to App store can we have the default setting on the notification center set to Alerts rather than banners?

Answer (score 1):

No. Anything within **Settings.app** in iOS devices is in the explicit control of the user of the device. Third party apps are not given access to change system settings and cannot set them to specific values (either while submitting an app to the App Store or during first run or at any other point in time).